# How do I commit in git annex on Windows (adjusted branch)

Tags: git, git-annex

I have a `git` and `git annex` project on a filesystem that does not suppport symlinks. Thus, I have to work with an adjusted branch, that means that on top of my "normal" branch I execute `git annex adjust --unlock` so that I get a new branch on which my annex'ed files are not symlinks into the annex store, but the original files. My commit tree looks then like this:

```
  *  git-annex adjusted branch (HEAD, adjusted/master(unlocked))
* ┘ some change (master, refs/basis/adjusted/master(unlocked))
* some prior change
...
```

When I commit now, I would do so on the adjusted branch I guess, because git-annex cannot create the symlinks, using `git annex add MYFILE` and git commit`:

```
  * my new commit (HEAD, adjusted/master(unlocked))
  *  git-annex adjusted branch 
* ┘ some change (master, refs/basis/adjusted/master(unlocked))
* some prior change
```

What I want is a commit to the master branch that is in the standard git-annex format, meaning that annex'ed files are symlinks to their place in the annex store. Finally, because I cannot have symlinks checked out at my file system, I need to automatically create a new adjusted branch that replaces the symlinks in the commit by the actual files.

So how do I get from the situation above to the following:

```
  *  git-annex adjusted branch (HEAD, adjusted/master(unlocked))
* ┘ my new commit (master, refs/basis/adjusted/master(unlocked))
│ *  git-annex adjusted branch (abandoned previous HEAD)
* ┘ some change
* some prior change
```

The git annex manual on [git annex adjust](https://git-annex.branchable.com/git-annex-adjust/) only tells me how to get an adjusted branch, but not how to reverse the adjusting. The [adjusting concept page](https://git-annex.branchable.com/design/adjusted_branches/#index5h2) is a bit cryptical for me (highlighted text mine).

> A user's commits on the adjusted branch have to be reverse adjusted to
> get changes to apply to the master branch.
>
> This reversal of one adjustment can be done as just another
> adjustment. Since only files touched by the commit will be reverse
> adjusted, it doesn't need to reverse all changes made by the original
> adjustment. [**how shall I reverse adjust from files to symlinks when my filesystem doesn't support them?**]
>
> For example, reversing the unlock adjustment might lock the file. Or,
> it might do nothing, which would make all committed files remain
> unlocked. [**what do they mean with "might do nothing"? What are the conditions?**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datalad project have written the function [datalad.support.AnnexRepo.localsync()](https://github.com/datalad/datalad/blob/2b92a764fdc64b750dad68eb51c817218a1ec153/datalad/support/annexrepo.py#L3468-L3524) to accomplish this. The core of that function is

> ```py
> def localsync(self, remote=None, managed_only=False):
>     """Consolidate the local git-annex branch and/or managed branches.
>     This method calls `git annex sync` to perform purely local operations
>     that:
>     1. Update the corresponding branch of any managed branch.
>     2. Synchronize the local 'git-annex' branch with respect to particular
>        or all remotes (as currently reflected in the local state of their
>        remote 'git-annex' branches).
>     If a repository has git-annex's 'synced/...' branches these will be
>     updated.  Otherwise, such branches that are created by `git annex sync`
>     are removed again after the sync is complete.
>     [...]
>     """
>     [...]
>     cmd = ['sync']
>     [...]
>     cmd.extend([
>         # disable any external interaction and other magic
>         '--no-push', '--no-pull', '--no-commit', '--no-resolvemerge',
>         '--no-content'])
>     self.call_annex(cmd)
>     # a sync can establish new config (e.g. annex-uuid for a remote)
>     self.config.reload()
>     # cleanup sync'ed branch if we caused it
>     if not had_synced_branch and synced_branch in self.get_branches():
>         lgr.debug('Remove previously non-existent %s branch after sync',
>                   synced_branch)
>         self.call_git(
>             ['branch', '-d', synced_branch],
>         )
> ```

so the command needed seems to be `git annex sync --no-push --no-pull --no-commit --no-resolvemerge --no-content`. This might generate special git annex branches whose names start with "synced/...", which might also already be there from a previous sync operation. So this function deletes them if they were not already present beforehand.